# JavaFX Text not scaling properly on high DPI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, screen-resolution

I'm working on a Java application that involves JavaFX. When I run the program on laptops or desktops, it looks fine. But when I run the program on a MS Surface with high DPI the font sizes are not properly scaled.

I have an instance of javafx.scene.text.Text added as a child to an instance of javafx.scene.Group. The Text is very big in comparison to the rest of the visuals.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Java reports itself as being DPI aware, so Windows doesn't scale it, when in fact it won't scale properly by itself. You can turn off this behaviour and force Windows to scale java GUI's, using this answer I found on superuser.

https://superuser.com/a/1207925

This works perfectly for me.